# How using 'as' works under the hood in angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-cli

```
<div>
  @if (user.name as userName) {
    {{ userName }}
  }
</div>



<div>
 @if (user.name) {
   {{ user.name }}
 }
</div>
```

I am wondering what is the difference between this two approaches? just a syntax? or something else? For example when using `as` does it creates variable? What is happening under the hood?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know how deep you want such an explaination to go.
if you really want to go down to each line of execution, I'm sorry.. I will not put hours into this question.
Basically this happens:

First of all, you have to keep in mind, what you are writing there, is a dialect that does resemble js, but isn't.

So to not go into too much depth and keep this somewhat reasonable, let's start at the point, where the parser will encounter a `@` symbol:
https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/c213a4e15a594ff141cf312ad301128e7ed4127c/packages/compiler/src/ml_parser/lexer.ts#L206-L207

```js
} else if (this._tokenizeBlocks && this._attemptCharCode(chars.$AT)) {
  this._consumeBlockStart(start);
```

basically what you see there, is that when encountering an `@`, it will consume the continuing data as block.

the consumption of that block will parse as follows:
https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/c213a4e15a594ff141cf312ad301128e7ed4127c/packages/compiler/src/ml_parser/lexer.ts#L245-L277

```js
private _consumeBlockStart(start: CharacterCursor) {
  this._beginToken(TokenType.BLOCK_OPEN_START, start);
  const startToken = this._endToken([this._getBlockName()]);

  if (this._cursor.peek() === chars.$LPAREN) {
    // Advance past the opening paren.
    this._cursor.advance();
    // Capture the parameters.
    this._consumeBlockParameters();
    // Allow spaces before the closing paren.
    this._attemptCharCodeUntilFn(isNotWhitespace);

    if (this._attemptCharCode(chars.$RPAREN)) {
      // Allow spaces after the paren.
      this._attemptCharCodeUntilFn(isNotWhitespace);
    } else {
      startToken.type = TokenType.INCOMPLETE_BLOCK_OPEN;
      return;
    }
  }

  if (this._attemptCharCode(chars.$LBRACE)) {
    this._beginToken(TokenType.BLOCK_OPEN_END);
    this._endToken([]);
  } else {
    startToken.type = TokenType.INCOMPLETE_BLOCK_OPEN;
  }
}

private _consumeBlockEnd(start: CharacterCursor) {
  this._beginToken(TokenType.BLOCK_CLOSE, start);
  this._endToken([]);
}
```

after all the blocks of your code are parsed, it will be thrown into angulars expression parser. (since `@` refers to an expression)

this will also go through, and parse the `as` bindings.
https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/c213a4e15a594ff141cf312ad301128e7ed4127c/packages/compiler/src/expression_parser/parser.ts#L1145-L1180

````js
/**
 * Parse a directive keyword, followed by a mandatory expression.
 * For example, "of items", "trackBy: func".
 * The bindings are: ngForOf -> items, ngForTrackBy -> func
 * There could be an optional "as" binding that follows the expression.
 * For example,
 * ```
 *   *ngFor="let item of items | slice:0:1 as collection".
 *                    ^^ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
 *               keyword    bound target   optional 'as' binding
 * ```
 *
 * @param key binding key, for example, ngFor, ngIf, ngForOf, along with its
 * absolute span.
 */
private parseDirectiveKeywordBindings(key: TemplateBindingIdentifier): TemplateBinding[] {
  const bindings: TemplateBinding[] = [];
  this.consumeOptionalCharacter(chars.$COLON);  // trackBy: trackByFunction
  const value = this.getDirectiveBoundTarget();
  let spanEnd = this.currentAbsoluteOffset;
  // The binding could optionally be followed by "as". For example,
  // *ngIf="cond | pipe as x". In this case, the key in the "as" binding
  // is "x" and the value is the template key itself ("ngIf"). Note that the
  // 'key' in the current context now becomes the "value" in the next binding.
  const asBinding = this.parseAsBinding(key);
  if (!asBinding) {
    this.consumeStatementTerminator();
    spanEnd = this.currentAbsoluteOffset;
  }
  const sourceSpan = new AbsoluteSourceSpan(key.span.start, spanEnd);
  bindings.push(new ExpressionBinding(sourceSpan, key, value));
  if (asBinding) {
    bindings.push(asBinding);
  }
  return bindings;
}
````

which will then go there:
https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/c213a4e15a594ff141cf312ad301128e7ed4127c/packages/compiler/src/expression_parser/parser.ts#L1202-L1223

````js
/**
 * Return the binding for a variable declared using `as`. Note that the order
 * of the key-value pair in this declaration is reversed. For example,
 * ```
 *   *ngFor="let item of items; index as i"
 *                              ^^^^^    ^
 *                              value    key
 * ```
 *
 * @param value name of the value in the declaration, "ngIf" in the example
 * above, along with its absolute span.
 */
private parseAsBinding(value: TemplateBindingIdentifier): TemplateBinding|null {
  if (!this.peekKeywordAs()) {
    return null;
  }
  this.advance();  // consume the 'as' keyword
  const key = this.expectTemplateBindingKey();
  this.consumeStatementTerminator();
  const sourceSpan = new AbsoluteSourceSpan(value.span.start, this.currentAbsoluteOffset);
  return new VariableBinding(sourceSpan, key, value);
}
````

and will then do a variable binding as seen here:
https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/c213a4e15a594ff141cf312ad301128e7ed4127c/packages/compiler/src/expression_parser/ast.ts#L343-L374

````js
/**
 * Return the binding for a variable declared using `as`. Note that the order
 * of the key-value pair in this declaration is reversed. For example,
 * ```
 *   *ngFor="let item of items; index as i"
 *                              ^^^^^    ^
 *                              value    key
 * ```
 *
 * @param value name of the value in the declaration, "ngIf" in the example
 * above, along with its absolute span.
 */
private parseAsBinding(value: TemplateBindingIdentifier): TemplateBinding|null {
  if (!this.peekKeywordAs()) {
    return null;
  }
  this.advance();  // consume the 'as' keyword
  const key = this.expectTemplateBindingKey();
  this.consumeStatementTerminator();
  const sourceSpan = new AbsoluteSourceSpan(value.span.start, this.currentAbsoluteOffset);
  return new VariableBinding(sourceSpan, key, value);
}
````

afterwards the bindings and other entities that drop out the AST compiler will be rendered here:
https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/c213a4e15a594ff141cf312ad301128e7ed4127c/packages/compiler/src/render3/view/template.ts#L2875-L2876

```js
const {nodes, errors, styleUrls, styles, ngContentSelectors, commentNodes} = htmlAstToRender3Ast(
  rootNodes, bindingParser, {collectCommentNodes: !!options.collectCommentNodes});
```

if you then go further into that function there, called `htmlAstToRender3Ast`, you will encounter a call to `HtmlAstToIvyAst` which then goes further into roughly 600 more lines of code that do yet another AST to AST convertion..

I could go further ofc, but as I said at the start, going deep will take a long time.

I hope you get a gist of how this somewhat works now.

essentially it parses this `as` expression as a variable expansion, like `let [foo, bar] = [1, 5]` in vanilla js. except in this case it's more like `[1, 5][0] as foo`

also a small reminder: all this code is ran every time you compile a template.

Answer (score 0):

The "as" keyword generates code that assigns the value to a temporary variable.

```
// Simplified representation of generated code
if (user.name) {
  let userName = user.name;
  // ... rest of the template block using userName
}
```

Use "as" for:
Cleaner template logic by introducing meaningful aliases.
Avoiding repetitive property access.

Avoid "as" when:
Not re-referencing the property within the block.
Unnecessary for clarity.